# Uninstall Entity Framework Tools 6.1.1 for VS 2012 removes Entity Data Model from new items

Tags: entity-framework

I have recently had issue using the Entity Framework 6.1.1 with my sqlite data provider. I was hoping to go back to EF 6.1.0 (I have update 2 installed) so I uninstalled Entity Framework 6.1.1 tools for visual studio 2013. After I did this I tried to add my Ado.Net entity data model but it has disappeared from the list of new items. Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Did you only uninstall the tools?  Or did you actually roll back the EF package as well?  Tell us exactly what you did, otherwise we'll just be guessing.

Comment: I uninstalled the tools, but I did not rollback the EF package, which is something I should have done.

Answer (score 0):

You must install the old EF Tools again (select Repair VS in controlpanel->programs & features). This is also written in the docs.

Comment: I tried the uninstall of EF tools, and then could not see the Add New Item -> Entity Data Model. But I will try again and this time do the repair. Thanks